# Django error :sdr_media' is not a valid tag library: Template library sdr_media not found . How to remove this error?

Tags: django

My sdr_media.py is in this path .

```
geodjango/geographic_admin/templates/templatetags/sdr_media.py
```

My layer_upload.html is in this folder

```
   geodjango/geographic_admin/template/maps
```

The code is this

```
{% load sdr_media %}
```

But , still the sdr_media tag is  not found . The templatetags folder has **init**.py for it to work . Is my path wrong ?

Edit

This is the sdr_media.py code

```
from django import template
from django.conf import settings

register = template.Library()

@register.tag('sdr_media')
def geonode_media(parser, token):
    try:
        tagname, argument = token.split_contents()
        argument = argument[1:-1] # get rid of quotes
        if not argument in settings.MEDIA_LOCATIONS:
            raise template.TemplateSyntaxError, '%s is not a valid resource name' % argument
        return MediaNode(argument)
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError, '%r requires a single argument' % token.contents.split()[0]

class MediaNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, resource):
        self.resource = resource

    def render(self, context):
        return settings.MEDIA_LOCATIONS[self.resource]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. `templatetags` directory should be in app directory, not in templates directory.

For example `myproject/myapp/templatetags/sdr_media.py`

Comment: I did that , but still now luck

Comment: @mekasperasky Do you have your app in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: TemplateSyntaxError at /data/upload
'sdr_media' is not a valid tag library: Template library sdr_media not found, tried django.templatetags.sdr_media,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.sdr_media . this is the error

Comment: And yes , the app is installed in myproject .

Answer (score 0):

I'd say: yes

> The app should contain a templatetags
>   directory, at the same level as
>   models.py, views.py, etc. If this
>   doesn’t already exist, create it

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem, and solved it:

1. apply DrTyrsa's answer (mandatory)
2. restart django server (mandatory)